# Adjust the height of a Dialog with custom layout in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog with custom layout, everything is working fine, except there is a big empty spaces at the top which i cannot remove.

Any suggestion how i can remove that empty space.

Here is my Code:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ConferenceDetailsActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.l_custom_dialog_name);

final CustomEditText nameText = (CustomEditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.confNameFld);
nameText.setText(mConferenceDetails.getConferenceName());

Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final CustomEditText nameText = (CustomEditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.confNameFld);
        String text = nameText.getText().toString();

        dialog.dismiss();

    }
});

dialog.show();
```

---

My xml Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/nameBackground"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/name_badge"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <com.invosys.iconference.CustomControls.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/confNameFld"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nameBackground"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nameBackground"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameBackground"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nameBackground"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/namePlaceholder"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textColor="@color/ECharcoalColor" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Ok "
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameBackground"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameBackground"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nameBackground" />
```

---

[image]

..........................

After i used this piece of code the size is reduced but it is still not unto the task;

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before setContentView    
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
```

[image]

Comment: could you please post your custom dialog xml?

Comment: i have edited the question, you can see the layout now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //before setContentView    
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logindialog);
```

Comment: can you upload another screen shot for that?

Comment: add this also and see how it looks like: dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: @Karim i have uploaded the image.

Comment: add android:scaleType="centerCrop" to your ImageView and let me know

Comment: Sorry because forget this question, you should check these conditions below:
1: Make sure the designed image has no padding or margin (they can transparent)./
2: Add android:layout_margin = "0dp" and android:layout padding="0dp" to the relative_layout (or imageview), then re-check it.